# how to convert RichText Area Data into JPEG image

Tags: gwt

How to convert the text and Images insert into the rich text area into a jpeg image in gwt

Answer (score 0):

since gwt rich text editor gives you the html as value you can use a server-side service to transform the html into image.

If you're using java on the server side I believe [this might help a bit](http://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/) although I never tried it before.